# How do I register a function to sqlContext UDF in scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a method called getAge(timestamp:Long) and I want to register this as a sql function.

I have

```
sqlContext.udf.register("getAge",getAge)
```

But its telling me I need arguments or use _ afterwards, I tried using _ but gives me error. How do I register it with an argument. I am new to scala so I have no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
sqlContext.udf.register("getAge",getAge)
```

should be:

```
sqlContext.udf.register("getAge",getAge _)
```

The underscore (must have a space in between function and underscore) turns the function into a partially applied function that can be passed in the registration.

#### More explanation

When we invoke a function, we have to pass in all the required parameters.  If we don't, the compiler will complain.

We can however ask it for the function as a value, with which we can pass in the required parameters at a later time.  How we do this is to use the underscore.

`getAge` means to run `getAge` - for example, `def getAge = 10` giving us `10`. We don't want the result, we want the function. Moreover, with your definition, the compiler sees that `getAge` requires a parameter, and complains that one wasn't given.

What we want to do here is to pass `getAge` as a function value.  We tell Scala, we don't know the parameter yet, we want the function as a value and we'll supply it with the required parameter at a later time.  So, we use `getAge _`.

Assuming signature for `getAge` is:

```
getAge(l: Long): Long = <function>
```

`getAge _` becomes an anonymous function:

```
Long => Long = <function>
```

which means it needs a parameter of type `Long` and the result of invoking it will yield a value of type `Long`.

Comment: So when I use the underscore, it knows the parameters as well? In other words, what is partially applied function mean?

Comment: I've updated the answer with an explanation and to answer your questions, yes. Partially applied function means the function as a value, rather than its result.  The result isn't yet here, we just want the function itself, and that we (the database framework in fact) are going to supply it with the parameter later.