# Filtering by Binary type in Spark sql

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a field which represents IP Address in my schema. I want to use the [Binary Type](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/BinaryType.html) to store the data.

The way I imagine this is if my ip is: `50.100.150.200` I will save it as `[50,100,150,200]` in a Byte array (the sequence sure matters but we can leave it out of the discussion in this question).

My question is how to filter by this column when I query? (String doesn't really fit the purpose)

For instance I want to run the following query:

```
SELECT * from table1 WHERE sourceip='50.100.150.200'
```

Here is a piece of code to demonstrate the problem:

Bean definition (for schema creation):

```
    public static class MyBean1 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private byte[] description;

    public MyBean1(int id, String name, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description.getBytes();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public byte[] getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(byte[] description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

Demo code (I want to filter by the description):

```
    List<MyBean1> newDebugData = new ArrayList<MyBean1>();
    newDebugData.add(new MyBean1(1, "Arnold", "10.150.15.10"));
    newDebugData.add(new MyBean1(1, "Bob", "10.150.15.11"));
    newDebugData.add(new MyBean1(3, "Bob", "10.150.15.12"));
    newDebugData.add(new MyBean1(3, "Bob", "10.150.15.13"));
    newDebugData.add(new MyBean1(1, "Alice", "10.150.15.14"));

    Dataset<Row> df2 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(newDebugData, MyBean1.class);
    df2.createTempView("table1");
    sqlContext.sql("select * from table1 where description='10.150.15.14'").show();
```

I am getting the error:

```
differing types in '(table1.`description` = CAST('10.150.15.14' AS DOUBLE))'
```

Comment: can you please share a reproducible example?

Comment: @moto please see my edit

Comment: For IPv4 addresses, we use LongType (not IntegerType because one bit is used for the sign).  We have a wrapper script that converts `where description='1.2.3.4'` to `where description = 16909060`  (16909060 = 0x01020304).  Our spark program contains a UDF that converts the column values back into dotted decimal: `results_df = results_df.withColumn('description', ipv4AsStr_udf(col('description')))`.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't 100% an answer to your question, but I hope the pointer will help.

The following question is not about filtering, but selecting data from an array. [selecting a range of elements in an array spark sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40134975/selecting-a-range-of-elements-in-an-array-spark-sql/40136386)

It looks like a lot of information there, including some guidance on UDFs to query arrays using Spark SQL.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thx for the tip, actually I saw this answer while researching. Please see my edit for the usecase

Answer (score 0):

[SPARK-21344](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21344) fixed the following issue in versions 2.0.3, 2.1.2, 2.2.1: BinaryType comparison does signed byte array comparison.  So binary comparisons should work with those releases.

The JIRA has the following scala test code:

```
case class TestRecord(col0: Array[Byte])
def convertToBytes(i: Long): Array[Byte] = {
   val bb = java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(8)
   bb.putLong(i)
   bb.array
}
val timestamp = 1498772083037L
val data = (timestamp to timestamp + 1000L).map(i => TestRecord(convertToBytes(i)))
val testDF = sc.parallelize(data).toDF
val filter1 = testDF.filter(col("col0") >= convertToBytes(timestamp) 
              && col("col0") < convertToBytes(timestamp + 50L))
assert(filter1.count == 50)
```

I don't know what the equivalent Java code would be, but that should get you started.

---

I mentioned in a comment above on the question that we use LongType to store IPv4 addresses. We have a wrapper script to convert dotted decimal to long integer, and a Spark UDF to go the other way: long integer to dotted decimal.  I assume LongType is faster for queries than BinaryType.